# How do I reference my existing routes when using a Rails 3.1 engine?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I'm using the [forem](https://github.com/radar/forem) engine in Rails 3.1, but my application layout references some resource routes such as `users_path` and `new_sprite_path`.

This all works fine outside the engine, but when I try to navigate to a page in the engine I get

```
undefined local variable or method `new_sprite_path' for #<#<Class:0x7f4faa4f9240>:0x7f4faa4dc320>
```

How can I get the engine to see the paths in my application correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `main_app.new_sprite_path`.

Comment: Hi, may I ask, once it's installed, are there steps you have to take (in config/routes.rb for example) to get it working? I have a users model, do I need an admin user model too so that I can create topics? right now, I can login but can't make posts or topics or anything. It looks just like this (doesn't seem right) https://twitter.com/#!/VanCrimLaw/status/143558602685292544/photo/1

Comment: this (https://github.com/radar/forem ) seems like code for the engine that forem is based on, but do you know of code for the demo app so we can actually so how to write the code for the models, controllers, views?